# Finding all the unique paths in a graph and return the cheapest

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a school project where i need to find all the different paths in a graph. It's like driving a car between different cities (nodes) and I need to go though all of them and find the cheapest path. I don't have a destination point, the goal is just to find the fastest way to go though all the cities. Starting point is 0. I am not sure how to start and which algorithm to use. I just started learning about graphs and trees, so any help would be appreciated :)

For example from city 0 to city 1 it's 20 minutes.

[image]

Comment: The most straightforward way to do this is using recursion -- writing a function that calls itself to solve smaller subproblems. Are you familiar with the concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good that you are trying to learn! I recommend you read up on the [Travelling Salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).